# How to use jest in clojurescript?

Tags: installation, jestjs, clojurescript

After I installing jest using `npm install jest` and adding "test":"jest" in package.json, I expect keywords like "expect" to work automatically in my cljs test files:

```
  (.toBeInTheDocument (expect (.getByText screen "Some Component")))
```

But I get that "expect" is undefined. js/expect gives undefined as well. How to get jest to work with clojurescript?

-- EDIT --

I installed lint a this library, but still can't get jest functions to work in my test file.

Comment: This might help https://github.com/athomasoriginal/demo-clojurescript-jest

Comment: That doesn't feel elegant

Comment: what does "I installed lint a this library" mean?
Did you try to use jest globals? https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api

Answer (score 1):

This is not what you asked, but I think most ClojureScript projects use tests written with [clojure.test](https://clojurescript.org/tools/testing) and mocking facilities of the language (eg. `with-redefs`), so I think it will be much easier to follow that path instead.

Check these links depending on the build tool that you use for your project:

- figwheel: https://figwheel.org/docs/testing.html
- shadow-cljs: https://shadow-cljs.github.io/docs/UsersGuide.html#_testing